# SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: My_Last_Call__c.Contact__r

Tags: soql, query, error

I'm trying to get a list, mlcs, of a custom objects "my last call date", which has a related contact, and add all of these contacts to a list of contacts, cs.

To use the .add() method, I need to use the contact__r suffix for the lookup field, Contact__c, or else I get an error. But, I have to query this field using the contact__c suffix, or else it will tell me that no row was found for contact__r. But if I do this, then it says I didn't query contact__r and cannot use it.

apex:

```
public class MyLastCallListView2{


public String currentUser = UserInfo.getUserId();


public list <My_Last_Call__c> mlcs {get;set;}
public list <contact> cs {get;set;}

   public void search(){  

       string callsList='select name,id, Contact__c, Contact_name__c, User__c from My_Last_Call__c WHERE User__c=\''+currentUser+'\'';  
 system.debug(callsList);
 mlcs= Database.query(callsList);  

 for (My_Last_Call__c m : mlcs){
 cs.add(m.Contact__r);
 }


   public MyLastCallListView2(ApexPages.StandardController controller){}





}
```

Error:
    `SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: My_Last_Call__c.Contact__r`

If I change `cs.add(m.Contact__r);` to `cs.add(m.Contact__c);` or `cs.add(m.Contact__c.id);`, the code will not compile, with this error: `Error: Compile Error: Incompatible element type Id for collection of Contact at line 22 column 2`

Comment: Why are you even using dynamic soql?

Comment: contact is child of `My_Last_Call__c` ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't use cross reference properly, you need to call at least one field of contact by using "Contact__r." Try to change :

```
string callsList='select name,id, Contact__c, Contact_name__c, User__c from My_Last_Call__c WHERE User__c=\''+currentUser+'\'';
```

**by**

```
string callsList='select name,id, Contact__c, Contact__r.Name, User__c from My_Last_Call__c WHERE User__c=\''+currentUser+'\'';
```

Comment: I tried this, fixed my original problem, but now I am getting a `Attempt to de-reference a null object` error at `cs.add`

Comment: you probably need to check if you Contact__c is not null before to add

Comment: It's not null, but you're right, I should add that to my code

Comment: Confusingly, when I look at my debug log, it shows that a Contact is returned:

`15:29:26.0 (33552960)|USER_DEBUG|[22]|DEBUG|contact: Contact:{Name=Dr. Moneybags, Id=00363000003xhDVAAY, RecordTypeId=012j00000010G5jAAE}`

Comment: You don't init cs list at the start, you need to create a new instance, cs = new list<contact>();

Comment: Oh I see. I shouldn't have used get;set to do that. Alright, I've made that change. I'll see if it works now.